# Access TextView from outer class

Tags: android

I am fairly new to Android and Java and hope you can help me with this.

I have a nested class:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

  {


    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();

        String loTude = "Longitude:" + loc.getLongitude();
        String laTude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLong)).setText(loTude);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLat)).setText(laTude);



    }
```

How can i access the two Strings loTude and laTude from my outer class?
Do i need to return them from the method via an object, or is there any other way?

Comment: write a method in this class that ll return 2 strings via a object to any class you want or write 2 methods that ll return loTude and laTude respectively :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nested class then make Global object of textview Like as....

```
    Class MyActivity extends Activity{
      public TextView tvLat,tvLng;
       @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

           tvLat=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLong);
           tvLng=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLat);

     }
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
        {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
              {
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();

            String loTude = "Longitude:" + loc.getLongitude();
            String laTude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();

            tvLat.setText(loTude);
            tvLng.setText(laTude);

        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by passing reference of your activity to your custom class. see below:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

  private Activity myActivity;

  public MyLocationListener(Activity act){
      myActivity = act;
  }

  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
      loc.getLatitude();
      loc.getLongitude();

      String loTude = "Longitude:" + loc.getLongitude();
      String laTude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();

      ((TextView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.tvLong)).setText(loTude);
      ((TextView) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.tvLat)).setText(laTude);

  }

}
```

this solution is recommended if you have defined your class separately. Otherwise, find your views in onCreate method and simply use them inside your inner class

Comment: better pass activity context in constructor rather than activity and create 2 textview using that context so that this class ll set Textviews text using context

Comment: sorry, you cant do **findViewById** from `Context`. So its reasonable to provide Activity's reference

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this

```
public class Global extends Application {
   public static String loTude =""; 
   public static String laTude ="";
}
```

use for string values

```
Global.loTude = "Longitude:" + loc.getLongitude();
Global.laTude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
```